# How to keep the cookie alive forever in Selenium scripts?

Tags: python, selenium, session-cookies, certificate-expiry

To create cookies with selenium:

**cookies.py**

```
import time
import json

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait    
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
target =  "xxx.yyy"
driver.get(target)
time.sleep(60)
with open('cookies.txt','w') as cookief:
    cookief.write(json.dumps(driver.get_cookies()))    
driver.close()
```

I logined the website `xxx.yyy` manually and created `cookies.txt` file,now login with the script:

**relogin.py**

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
target = "xxx.yyy"
driver.get(target)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
with open('cookies.txt','r') as cookief:
    cookieslist = json.load(cookief)
    for cookie in cookieslist:
        if 'expiry' in cookie:
            del cookie['expiry']
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.refresh()
```

The target website can relogin with `python3 relogin.py`,tomorrow i try again with `python3 relogin.py`,it failed,the cookies lasted  for almost one day long.How to keep the cookie alive forever  in Selenium scripts ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you figure out a solution?